# Can I rent a motorized boat on Koh Phi Phi Don without a license?

Tags: rental, phi-phi

Can I rent a small motorized boat that will accommodate three people to drive around the island for a few hours? All I have is a european driving license.

I know that I can hire a longboat but this is not what the question is about.

Comment: Drive by yourself? Probably not but rent it with their captain for your small group is always an option.

Comment: Whether you can and should are rather different questions.  For example, you could probably rent a powerful motorbike without a suitable licence.  The catch is that you won't have any insurance.  If you crash or it's stolen then you are in big trouble.

Answer (score 1):

For the Phi Phi islands, the iconic longtail boats are a way of life, and of livelihood; they're everywhere.  While it's easy to rent a longtail, it may be difficult, if not impossible to find an owner willing to part with his craft and let you take off on your own. If you're staying on the island, many accommodations have speedboats for hire, along with a driver and the necessary safety equipment and insurance. There, you may find one which would allow you to take the boat out unaccompanied. More realistically, kayaks can be rented on either Loh Dalam Bay or Tonsai Beach and allow you to explore independently.